# Apply the chain rule with partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

[image]

Hey all,

I'm looking for resources on how to apply the chain rule to multi-variate partial derivatives.  I'm pretty stumped about how to get ${df\over dx}$  and ${df\over d\mu}$ for the above function.

A step-by-step would be helpful but if there are online resources somewhere that practice problems that do this, with the reasoning behind their solutions that'd be all the better.

For example, I've found resources - https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/differentiating-vector-valued-functions/a/partial-derivatives-of-parametric-surfaces - that parameterize the function in terms of another variable `t`, but I'm unsure if I should do that to this problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is $\mathbf{x}$? A vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes that's correct